# Is EC El Gamal the only option?

Tags: elliptic-curves, elgamal-encryption

This question is related to the question I asked [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60043/commutative-homomorphic-encryption-for-zero-knowledge-transfers). I'm looking for encryption scheme with the following properties:

Given $m$ is a 256-bit value, $pub_a$ and $pub_b$ are public keys, and $priv_a$ is a private key for $pub_a$:

1. $E'(E(m, pub_a), pub_b) = E'(E(m, pub_b), pub_a)$, where $E'$ is a re-encryption function
2. $E(m + x, pub_a) = E(m, pub_a) ⊕ E(x, pub_a)$, where $⊕$ could be either $+$ or $*$
3. $D(E(m, pub_a), priv_a) = m$

It seems like non-randomized "exponential" version of EC El Gamal (as described [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14437/elgamal-with-elliptic-curves-i)) satisfies conditions 1 and 2, but 3 would be difficult to do for large values of $m$. There are potential ways to get around this, but I'm wondering if there is another encryption scheme that could be used instead. (note: using non-randomized version should not compromise security because messages would be randomly padded prior to encryption).

Specifically, I came across [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjtooSk1NjbAhXorlQKHSSdAEgQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783319521527-c2.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1599092-p180559084&usg=AOvVaw3apqSw1j8B5Oa33MBtK0nx) paper which in section 3.2 describes something that might work for my purposes. Unfortunately, my ability to read scientific literature is not advanced enough for me to fully understand the proposed scheme.

---

Explanation of how a modified EC El Gamal satisfies conditions 1:

Assuming $G$ is a generator point, $m$ is a padded message, $x_a$ and $x_b$ are private keys, and $X_a$ and $X_b$ are corresponding public keys, we can do:

- $k_a = H(X_a)$, $k_b = H(X_b)$, where $H$ is some hash function
- Encrypting $m$ with $X_a$ we get: $C_a = (k_aG, mG + k_aX_a)$
- Encrypting $m$ with $X_b$ we get: $C_b = (k_bG, mG + k_bX_b)$

We can then define re-encryption as follows:

- $C_{ab} = (k_aG + k_bG, mG + k_aX_a + k_bX_b)$
- $C_{ba} = (k_bG + k_aG, mG + k_bX_b + k_aX_a)$

So, we have $C_{ab} = C_{ba}$

Comment: Ohh, I missread the question and assumed you wanted $\oplus$ be applied on the plaintexts (instead of standard sum). Obviously you don't care what happens with the ciphertexts.

Comment: Does $+$ mean addition of integers $\bmod n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$? (eg you don't want addition of points on an elliptic curve?)

Comment: Yes, it should be integer addition. Just to give a concrete example using numbers: $E(9, pub_a) = E(2, pub_a) ⊕ E(7, pub_a)$.

Comment: I don't see how "exponential" EC ElGamal satisfies point 1. The message space and ciphertext space are different, so you can't re-encrypt a ciphertext. Assuming that you don't really care about point 1, the standard way to construct an additive homomorphic cryptosystem is to use Paillier: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78999/discussion-on-question-by-irakliy-is-ec-el-gamal-the-only-option).