# Zero-knowledge integer comparison

Tags: elliptic-curves, zero-knowledge-proofs

This question is a follow up to the question I asked [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60074/zero-knowledge-transfer-of-value-protocol-inspired-by-ec-el-gamal). Basically, the protocol I described  has a flaw (as pointed out in this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/60078/57663)), and I am trying to figure out how to address it. The setup is:

- Alice has a secret value $a$ to which she's publicly committed by sharing $A=a∗G+X_a$, where $X_a$ is her public key
- She calculates a new value $a' = a - c$
- And then  publicly commits to $C = c *G$ and to $A′=a'∗G+X_a$

An independent observer can check that the math was done correctly by verifying that $A=A′+C$. However, this doesn't quite work because Alice can underflow $a$ and the verification would still pass.

One way to address it that I can think of is for Alice to prove that $a > c$ (or that $a' < a)$, but I'm not sure how this can be done without revealing $a$ or $c$.

---

**Edit2**: removed a potential approach because it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Statement $a > c$
could be proved as $a - c - 1 = b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2 + b_4^2$.
According to Lagrange theorem,
a 4-tuple of integers exists for any non-negative integer such that it equals to the sum of squares.
This kind of proof was suggested by Helger Lipmaa (On diophantine complexity and statistical zero-knowledge arguments. ASIACRYPT 2003).
Proving statements about integers (not finite field elements) committed with [Okamoto-Fujisaki commitment scheme](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221355462_Statistical_Zero_Knowledge_Protocols_to_Prove_Modular_Polynomial_Relations), is doable
with a group of order hidden from Prover.

Scenario described previously looks somewhat like a [Zcash JoinSplit](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zcash/zips/master/protocol/protocol.pdf) (section 1.2 High-level Overview).

Comment: Would you mind and [edit] links to the mentioned ressources (JoinSplit, Stadler-Camenisch,...) into your answer?

Comment: Does Okamoto-Fujisaki commitment scheme imply trusted setup? After going through the paper it seems like it, but also my ability to understand scientific literature is pretty limited. So, I might be wrong.

Comment: @irakliy Setup is trusted in a sense that Prover must not know modulus factorization, and modulus itself must be properly generated.